# Apache Spark Handling Skewed Data

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables I would like to join together. One of them has a very bad skew of data. This is causing my spark job to not run in parallel as a majority of the work is done on one partition.

I have heard and read and tried to implement salting my keys to increase the distribution. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyfHUNnMutg at 12:45 seconds is exactly what I would like to do.

Any help or tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you should use salted keys on the larger table (via randomization) and then replicate the smaller one / cartesian join it to the new salted one:

Here are a couple of suggestions:

> Tresata skew join RDD   https://github.com/tresata/spark-skewjoin
>
> python skew join:
>   https://datarus.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/fighting-the-skew-in-spark/

The `tresata` library looks like this:

```
import com.tresata.spark.skewjoin.Dsl._  // for the implicits   

// skewjoin() method pulled in by the implicits
rdd1.skewJoin(rdd2, defaultPartitioner(rdd1, rdd2),   
DefaultSkewReplication(1)).sortByKey(true).collect.toLis
```

Comment: Is there any scala library that does a skew join?

Also in the second link you provided. They are taking the first dataframes key and adding a random number to it. In the second dataframe they are replicating the key n times where n is the range of randomness you added to the first dataframe. This seems manageable when the second dataframe is small. Is this the exact and only way to do my above question?

Comment: I have successfully imported import com.tresata.spark.skewjoin.Dsl._
But I cannot find the .skewJoin method on my rdd of RDD[(String, row)]

Comment: I was execute the following:
rdd1.skewJoin(rdd2, defaultPartitioner(rdd1, rdd2), DefaultSkewReplication(1)).sortByKey(true).collect.toList

But need three imports

    import com.twitter.algebird.CMSHasherImplicits._
    import org.apache.spark.Partitioner.defaultPartitioner
    import com.tresata.spark.skewjoin.Dsl._