# Balanced RDD partition among workers - Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am working with an `RDD` of `x: key, y: set(values)` called `file`.

```
#values: RDD of tuples (key, val)    
file = values.groupByKey().mapValues(set).cache()
info_file = array(file.map(lambda (x,y): len(y)).collect())
var = np.var(info_file) #extremely high
def f():
     ...
file.foreachPartition(f)
```

The variance of `len(y)` is extremely high, such that around 1% of the pairs' sets (verified with percentile method) makes the 20% of the total number of values in the sets `total = np.sum(info_file)`.
If Spark partitions randomly with shuffle, there're high chances that that 1% may fall in the same partition, making unbalanced loads among workers.

Is there a way to make sure that 'heavy' tuples are euqally distributed among partitions? 
I actually split the `file` in two partitions, `heavy` and `light`, based on a threshold value of `len(y)` given by `threshold = np.percentile(info_file,99.9)` in order to separate this group of tuples and then re-partition.

```
light = file.filter(lambda (x,y): len(y) < threshold).cache()
heavy = file.filter(lambda (x,y): len(y) >= threshold).cache()

light.foreachPartition(f)
heavy.foreachPartition(f)
```

but get almost the same running time. The load might be already optimized, just want to check if I can do something more / better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ganglia to monitor cluster load. That should give you a very good indication of any data skew that might cause uneven cluster load.

If you do have an unfortunate data skew, there are ways of battling it by for instance restructuring data or salting keys. See for instance [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960599/apache-spark-handling-skewed-data).

Note that you can also do, what you are doing now, with splitting the data into `heavy` partitions and `light` partitions, but in that case you want to `cache` the `file` - not `heavy` and `light` - since it is `file` you need to process multiple times. Like this:

```
cachedFile = file.cache()

light = cachedFile.filter(lambda (x,y): len(y) < threshold)
heavy = cachedFile.filter(lambda (x,y): len(y) >= threshold)

light.foreachPartition(f)
heavy.foreachPartition(f)
```

Hope it helps.